# Batched average euclidian distance

Tags: tensorflow, linear-algebra

I need to calculate the average euclidian distance between a tensor x and a set of tensors ys (represented in tensorflow as a single tensor with an additional dimension). For a feasible training the calculation has to be batched (only the xs, the ys stay the same), also the calculation has to be differentiable, I don't know if the broadcasting violates this requirement. I know how to calculate the average over all tensors and also the euclidian distance between xs and ys, where xs has the same dimensionality as ys, but here I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out (x and y are both of shape `(number, input)`):

```
def pairwiseL2Norm(x, y):
    x_reshaped = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 1, num_input])
    y_reshaped = tf.reshape(y, shape=[1, -1, num_input])
    x_squared = x_reshaped*x_reshaped
    y_squared = y_reshaped*y_reshaped
    multiplied = x_reshaped * y_reshaped

    #x^2-2xy+y^2
    #((x_i)_xy)^2-2*((x_i)_xy)((y_j)_xy)+((y_j)_xy)^2
    combined = x_squared - 2*multiplied + y_squared

    summed = tf.reduce_sum(combined, axis=2)
    return tf.sqrt(summed)
```

and then the average:

```
distance = tf.reduce_mean(pairwiseL2Norm(gen_images, features), axis=1)
```